# New Monterey install: No disk access

Tags: install, permission, monterey, administrator

**PROBLEM...**

---

After an erase and install upgrade to Monterey (from Big Sur) the main admin user account has no access to any of the disks.

**HAVE TRIED...**

---

1. Checking if the user has admin privileges (it does)
2. Endless searches on the internet (probably using the wrong terms though)
3. Adding the admin user to the disk (don't have permissions)
4. Adding the Administrators group to the disk (don't have permissions)

[image: Screenshot of hard disk info dialog]

**QUESTIONS...**

---

I've never seen anything like this, especially after a clean erase and install.

1. Is this a new security protocol or is something off?
2. Should I try to brute force it in Terminal or just reinstall?

I don't won't a quick Terminal fix only to discover endless problems later as I performed the reinstall to fix stuff.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, I can now add my user account to the root-level of the work partition. But the top-level of the system drive is now fully locked down - is that right?